# PyTorch logistic regression model always predicts the same label no matter what

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, logistic-regression

I'm creating a logistic regression model with PyTorch for my research project, but I'm new to PyTorch and machine learning. The features are arrays of 4 elements, and the output is one value, but it ranges continuously from -180 to 180. I'm trying to implement my code with a sigmoid activation function, where the output will be multiplied by 360 and then 180 will be subtracted from it. However, my code is only giving 180 as an output, and I'm not sure why.

This is what each feature and label looks like:

```
Feature: [tensor(150), tensor(1., dtype=torch.float64), tensor(4.6000, dtype=torch.float64), tensor(150.0100, dtype=torch.float64)]
Label: tensor(-83.1838, dtype=torch.float64)
```

Here is my neural net:

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)

 def forward(self, x):
        outputs = torch.sigmoid(self.linear1(x))
        outputs = (outputs * 360) - 180 # range of phase shifts is [-180, 180]; we will calculate it from [0, 360] and shift down by 180
        return outputs

epochs = 100  # 200000 (start small for now)
input_dim = 4
output_dim = 1
learning_rate = 0.001
model = NeuralNetwork(input_dim, output_dim)
criterion = nn.SmoothL1Loss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

xTrain, xTest = Tensor(xTrain), Tensor(xTest)
yTrain, yTest = Tensor(yTrain), Tensor(yTest)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    predicted_outputs = model(xTrain)
    loss = criterion(torch.squeeze(predicted_outputs), yTrain)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
        print('Epoch:', epoch+1, ', Loss =', loss.item())
        print(predicted_outputs)

with torch.no_grad():
    predicted_ps = model(xTest)
    actual_value = torch.max(predicted_ps.data, 1)
    print("Predicted values: ")
    print(predicted_ps[0:20])
    print("actual phase shifts: ")
    print(yTest[0:20])
```

Here is my output:

```
Epoch: 10 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 20 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 30 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 40 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 50 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 60 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 70 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 80 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 90 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
Epoch: 100 , Loss = 164.7936248779297
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        ...,
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]], grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)

Predicted values: 
tensor([[180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.],
        [180.]])
actual phase shifts: 
tensor([ 90.0530,  25.6106, 105.7963, -30.9331,  21.8772, -31.4635, -85.8795,
         38.0100,  78.5014,  78.9565, -66.1851,   2.7738,  57.9369, 129.6264,
        -72.9741,  77.3210,  43.7826, -22.5292,  48.7709,  53.5080])
```

I used SmoothL1Loss() for my loss function since I read [here](https://medium.com/udacity-pytorch-challengers/a-brief-overview-of-loss-functions-in-pytorch-c0ddb78068f7) that it's ideal for regression and when features have large values. I've tried using Cross-Entropy Loss as well, but it gave the same output (though the loss was much larger). It's clear to me that the model is not learning for some reason, but I have no idea what to fix. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) Have you tried with a simple `MSELoss` first? (b) Try to use `momentum=0.9` on `SGD` and consider to set also `weight_decay`. (c) Try with different values of `lr` (e.g. 1e-1, 1e-2, etc.), until you nail down a good value that makes your loss decrease. (d) Note that you should also define a validation set, to prevent overfitting on the test set.

Comment: I tried it with `MSELoss` but the loss was `42156.6484375` for each epoch and the outputs are now all -180. What does `momentum` do? I tried adding it but nothing seemed to change. Same thing with `weight_decay`.

Comment: Just a question, but would the loss of your model be really great if you predict 179 degrees when the answer is -179? I've done work in predicting angles before and to account for cyclic outputs we predicted the `sin` and `cos` of the angles and then recombined using `arctan`.

Comment: The loss should ideally be very great since for my research, 179 would have very different implications compared to -179, so unfortunately I don't think using `sin` and `cos` would work too well for my model.

Comment: @becks Check [this](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/sgd-with-momentum/) for a small explanation on momentum. You can also scale the labels to predict a value between -1 and 1 and in inference, you simply multiply the net output by 180. In this way, the loss should be more stable. If you aren't aware of it, I suggest you explore the concept of [hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization)